# Как изменить символы в файле через putback? C++

Tags: c++, файлы

Написал код, который читает файл посимвольно и необходимые символы меняет на нужные:

```
// m_stream - это std::fstream
void changeSymbolsTo(char from, char to) {

    char c;

    while (m_stream.get(c)) {

        if (c == from) {
            m_stream.putback(to);
        }

    }

    m_stream.flush();

}
```

В итоге открываю файл, а он не изменился. Сел в отладчик, дебаггер показывает, что все работает нормально. Символы определяются, putback их пихает обратно в поток и следующим символом становится тот, что пихнули в putback. То есть поток модифицируется так, как надо, но изменения на файл не применяются. Почему в данном случае не работает flush()? Ведь именно эта функция должна слить все изменения в файл?

Comment: putback временно меняет буфер **входного потока**, никто и не думал отображать эти изменения на файл

Comment: @avp А можно ли отобразить эти изменения на файл, без создания копии?

Comment: Лучший способ как угодно менять файл, это  [ммапнуть](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) его и менять по месту

Comment: @avp я почитал побольше, думаю, что можно сделать свою обертку вокруг streambuf, который будет делать нужные изменения и толкнуть его в параметры fstream

Comment: Флаг в руки. [C++ is Good for the Economy, It Creates Jobs!](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/)